# Hadoop Hive: How to Select FROM tableX m1, tableX m2?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

How to write a Hive SQL query that for a table with two fields `id, val` will return groups of id-s where all id-s in a group have one and the same `val`?

The following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m1.id,
  m2.id
FROM tableX m1,
  tableX m2
WHERE m1.id <> m2.id
AND m1.val   = m2.val;
```

fails with:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:42 
cannot recognize input near 'm1' ',' 
'match' in table source
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to look at those groups, you can simply write:

```
select id, val
from tableX
order by val;
```

If you need to have those groups separated as different object, then you can use something like:

```
select val, collect_set(id)
from tableX
group by val;
```

Or (if the val is not important)

```
select collect_set(id)
from tableX
group by val;
```

Those queries will produce arrays of id's with no duplicates. `collect_list` (as of hive 0.13) is for aggregating collections with duplicates.

Comment: Thanks! Providing a record in `tableX` has two more fields: `a` and `b`, what query will output them together with every `id` in request with `collect_set`?

Comment: Well... that's a material for a different question. You could think of something like `select collect_set(named_struct('id', id, 'a', a, 'b', b)) from tableX group by val;`, but for now `collect_set` doesn't accept complex types (you have to patch it yourself to change that). So, e.g. assuming `id`, `a` and `b` are strings that don't contain `|` you cold write: `select collect_set(concat_ws('|', id, a, b)) from tableX group by val;`. This will create for every `val` an array of strings `id|a|b` which you would then have to split by `|`.

Comment: I tried `concat_ws` and got: `FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'collect_set' '(' 'concat_ws'`

Comment: It was my typo in select, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation, not a join for this:

```
SELECT m.val
FROM tableX m
GROUP BY m.val
HAVING MIN(m.id) = MAX(m.id);
```

The `HAVING` clause could also be:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id) = 1
```

But `COUNT(DISTINCT)` is usually more computationally intensive than `MIN()`/`MAX()`.

Comment: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 1:64 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'id'